# FileNotFoundException : mybatis configuration, mappers

Tags: java, maven, mybatis

There is my first deploying maven project.
I developed based on Netty and myBatis

edited:

This is under `src` directory tree.

```
├─main
│  ├─java
│  │  └─kr
│  │      └─stocktalk
│  │          ├─chat
│  │          │  ├─bean
│  │          │  ├─client
│  │          │  ├─codec
│  │          │  ├─common
│  │          │  └─lib
│  │          ├─cloudmessage
│  │          ├─db
│  │          │  ├─clients
│  │          │  └─dynamo
│  │          │      └─mappers
│  │          ├─handler
│  │          │  ├─chat
│  │          │  └─page
│  │          └─mybatis
│  │              ├─bean
│  │              ├─mapper
│  │              └─sql
│  └─resources
│      ├─error
│      ├─html
│      │  └─test
│      ├─mybatis
│      │  └─sql
│      └─snippet
└─test
    ├─java
    └─resources
```

And here is my `target` directories result of `mvn compile`

```
pom.xml
targets
├─classes
│  └─kr
│      └─stocktalk
│          ├─chat
│          │  ├─bean
│          │  ├─client
│          │  ├─codec
│          │  ├─common
│          │  ├─handler
│          │  └─lib
│          ├─cloudmessage
│          ├─db
│          │  ├─clients
│          │  └─dynamo
│          │      └─mappers
│          ├─handler
│          │  └─page
│          └─mybatis
│              ├─bean
│              ├─mapper
│              └─sql
├─generated-sources
│  └─annotations
├─resources
│  ├─error
│  ├─html
│  │  └─test
│  ├─mybatis
│  │  └─sql
│  └─snippet
└─test-classes
```

I want to place `mybatis-conf.xml` under `resources/mybatis` having mybatis configuration informations.

In `SqlSessionFactoryManager` class,
I wrote code like this

```
String resource = System.getProperty("user.dir") 
                + "/target/resources/mybatis/mybatis-conf.xml";
Reader reader = Resources.getResourceAsReader(resource);

if (sqlSessionFactory == null) {

    sqlSessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder()
                        .build(reader);
}
...
```

But error occurs.

> java.io.IOException: Could not find resource d:\workspace\stocktalk-chat/target/resources/mybatis/mybatis-conf.xml

When I tried to load `mybatis-conf.xml` with absolute path,
then loding a file is fine, good. well.. now I can see another problem.

> The error may exist in mybatis/sql/User.xml
>   Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing SQL Mapper Configuration. Cause: java.io.IOException: Could not find resource mybatis/sql/User.xml

Why `getResourceAsReader` cannot find my configruation file?
And How can I load `mybatis-conf.xml` with relative path ?

Comment: There is not enough information in issue, but you need configure your build that folder `mybatis` will be copied to folder `target/classes`. After that both User.xml and mybatis-conf.xml will be loadable through classpath

Comment: @michaldo Thankyou michaldo. What information should be attached that I get an answer?

Comment: @michaldo When I declared resoure targetPath to `<targetPath>resources</targetPath>` then working well, thank you so much. 
Can I ask one more question? If I want locating `resources` under `target` path(same path with `classes`) how can I do for this?

Comment: You don't presented sources layout of your project. You show only target folder structure (with typo I think: target`s`). Usually, there is no folder like target/resources, so you have unusal configuration. Anyway, I could blindly advice that folder `mybatis` should be placed in `src/main/resources`

Answer (score 2):

I think you use maven in you project.so ,when the maven project package(mvn package or mvn compile),if you do not config the build element,then the maven only default move class file to target.So if you want to package the *.properties *.xml *..... files to target ,you must config the resources element under build element
for example:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
```

and if you look the file(mybatis-config.xml) is you path ,and it really not exists.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would help to review how Maven works.

You shouldn't have a reference in your code to the `target` folder as this is a folder that maven uses to put the result of different build processes and stage for building the final artifact, and will most likely not be present on your final deployment environment. Ideally you wouldn't need to modify this folder manually.

Now to answer your question, mybatis configuration and mapper configuration files are generally considered part of your code and the final application. That's why they are placed in the `resources` folder in the `src` so they would end up as part of the final build artifact and as part of the classpath when the application is finally deployed. You are supposed to access them through means of classpath.

The below is an example from [mybatis doc website](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/java-api.html) on how to read the xml configuration of mybatis:

```
String resource = "org/mybatis/builder/mybatis-config.xml";
InputStream inputStream = Resources.getResourceAsStream(resource);
SqlSessionFactoryBuilder builder = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder();
SqlSessionFactory factory = builder.build(inputStream);
```

In your case the first line should be:
`String resource = "mybatis/mybatis-conf.xml";`

And as for the mapper location, this needs to be configured again as a classpath resource in the `mybatis-conf.xml`

Examples from [mybatis doc website](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#mappers) (scroll to the bottom):

```
<!-- Using classpath relative resources -->
<mappers>
  <mapper resource="org/mybatis/builder/AuthorMapper.xml"/>
  <mapper resource="org/mybatis/builder/BlogMapper.xml"/>
  <mapper resource="org/mybatis/builder/PostMapper.xml"/>
</mappers>

<!-- Using url fully qualified paths -->
<mappers>
  <mapper url="file:///var/mappers/AuthorMapper.xml"/>
  <mapper url="file:///var/mappers/BlogMapper.xml"/>
  <mapper url="file:///var/mappers/PostMapper.xml"/>
</mappers>

<!-- Using mapper interface classes -->
<mappers>
  <mapper class="org.mybatis.builder.AuthorMapper"/>
  <mapper class="org.mybatis.builder.BlogMapper"/>
  <mapper class="org.mybatis.builder.PostMapper"/>
</mappers>

<!-- Register all interfaces in a package as mappers -->
<mappers>
  <package name="org.mybatis.builder"/>
</mappers>
```

So in your case if you are only using xml mapper, and from the message you posted, add the following to your `mybatis-conf.xml`:

```
<mappers>
  <mapper resource="mybatis/sql/User.xml"/>
</mappers>
```

Answer (score 0):

If `mybatis-conf.xml` were under main/resources, then in your code you could do this and not worry about the physical path:

```
new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(super.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("mybatis-conf.xml"))
```

`mybatis-conf.xml` will be found on the classpath. If you do want it under `main/resources/mybatis` you may be able to do:

`new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(super.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("mybatis/mybatis-conf.xml"))`.

Your target resources folder should be part of the classpath when you run your Maven application, so specifying resources in not necessary. Also, your `User.xml` should exist under `main/resources/mybatis/sql/User.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are mistakes in your this code:

```
String resource = System.getProperty("user.dir") 
            + "/target/resources/mybatis/mybatis-conf.xml";
```

The `/` should be `\`.